# node-0.12.7_1 already installed, it's just not linked

Tags: node.js, npm

So, lately i checked my npm version and got this error message:

```
Yogies-MacBook-Pro:bin yogieputra$ node --version
v0.12.7
Yogies-MacBook-Pro:bin yogieputra$ npm --version
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
Yogies-MacBook-Pro:bin yogieputra$ brew install npm
Warning: node-0.12.7_1 already installed, it's just not linked
```

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Try `brew link --overwrite --dry-run npm`

Comment: already do that then I checked npm --version still the same error: -bash: npm: command not found

Answer (score 2):

Run `brew link node`or `brew doctor`.

You could need `sudo` so `sudo brew link node`

Comment: try brew doctor and got this message: Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
    node
brew link
Yogies-MacBook-Pro:~ yogieputra$ brew link
This command requires a keg argument
Yogies-MacBook-Pro:~ yogieputra$

Comment: where is node? `brew link node` not `brew link`

Comment: ah, here: Yogies-MacBook-Pro:cobainmap yogieputra$ brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.7_1... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/node
Target /usr/local/bin/node
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/node'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node

Comment: So? Can't you follow what it said? `brew link --overwrite node`

Answer (score 1):

To link already installed node, run following command:

```
brew link homebrew/versions/node012
```

For further explanation, you can go through [this](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/01/warning-node-already-installed-its-just.html).